# Hibernate ORM Failed:org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for:

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I am having a problem in hibernate config xml.

Entity:

```
package com.ds.supercar.model.places;
```

public class Location {

```
private int locationid;
private String street;
private String city;
private String state;
private String pin;

public Location() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public Location(int locationid, String street, String city, String state, String pin) {
    super();
    this.locationid = locationid;
    this.street = street;
    this.city = city;
    this.state = state;
    this.pin = pin;
}

public int getLocationid() {
    return locationid;
}

public void setLocationid(int locationid) {
    this.locationid = locationid;
}

public String getStreet() {
    return street;
}

public void setStreet(String street) {
    this.street = street;
}

public String getCity() {
    return city;
}

public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}

public String getState() {
    return state;
}

public void setState(String state) {
    this.state = state;
}

public String getPin() {
    return pin;
}

public void setPin(String pin) {
    this.pin = pin;
}
```

}

hbm xml file:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="com.ds.supercar.model.places.Location" table="supercarlocation" schema="supercar">
    <id name="locationid" column="locationid">
        <generator class="increment"/>
    </id>
    <property name="street"/>
    <property name="city"/>
    <property name="state"/>
    <property name="pin"/>
    </class>
```

Exception:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.hibernate.cfg.Environment).
```

log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Initial SessionFactory creation Failed:org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: com.ds.supercar.model.places.Location, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(branchlocation)]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at Test.main(Test.java:19)
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: com.ds.supercar.model.places.Location, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(branchlocation)]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:244)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:231)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.isValid(Property.java:174)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:308)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:186)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validate(Configuration.java:816)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1050)
    at Test.main(Test.java:13)

Please help me with this exception:

Comment: Is this the only table and entity you have?

Answer (score 0):

it seems you forgot to put mapping resource in your hibernate config file(**between sessionFactory tags**)
so use this and map your hbm's.

`<mapping resource="com.ds.supercar.model.places.Location.hbm.xml" />`

hope this helps you!

Comment: MR1:  I have already added mapping resource in config file     <mapping resource="com/ds/supercar/resources/mappings/locations/branch.hbm.xml"/>
<mapping resource="com/ds/supercar/resources/mappings/locations/location.hbm.xml"/>

Comment: maybe you should check your Hibernate Class or check your jdbc driver and etc .. to fix all of this ,you can follow this tutorial : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_examples.htm a quick guess is use default-lazy="false" and auto-import="true" in hibernate-mapping tag .